# Setting up AppDynamics with Adobe Experience Manager AEM

Tags: aem, appdynamics

I am trying to setup the AppDynamics java agent. I am facing issues in loading java agent in the JVM.

I try to add the below argument to the start.bat jvm options.
-javaagent:C:\javaagent.jar

However, the aem do not start after this.

I have kept AppMachineAgent folder in the same drive as the AEM installation. However, javaagent.jar is not kept in the bin folder of the AEM. Do I need to keep it in the bin folder?

Any suggested steps I am missing?

Comment: Java jar location doesn't matter. You need to check 2 things: jar is from the right platform (windows 32/64 and matches jvm) and files have correct permission. Also can you paste error from error logs to see where AEM is stuck in starting up?

Comment: Once AEM is started, agent starts successfully and logs the message that Started AppDynamics Java Agent successfully. However, it throws the below error in the startup console subsequently.
Event Dispatcher: Error during dispatch. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Can you provide full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the line below in the crx-quickstart/conf/sling.properties:

`org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=com.singularity.*,com.yourkit.*, ${org.apache.sling.launcher.bootdelegation}`